# Using Flutter, how to display a NetworkImage from local storage when OFFLINE

Tags: image, flutter, widget, offline, avatar

I am developing a tablet app using Flutter and I have a Widget to display a users avatar in a circle decoration. For this purpose I am using a Network image to display the image received from the server. However, there is the case of OFFLINE mode. For this purpose, I am storing users information and avatar as a **png** file in the external storage using **path_provider** package. A user can see his information but so far I could not find a way to display the avatar in this circular decoration. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with this. Following is my code for Widgets state and you can find my trial and commented out code in the first else case of the **build** function:

```
    class _UserCardState extends State<UserCard> {
      int id;
      String title;
      String name;
      String surname;
      String password;
      String imageDIR;
    
      var img;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        this.id = widget.id;
        this.title = widget.title;
        this.name = widget.name;
        this.surname = widget.surname;
        this.password = widget.password;
        this.imageDIR = widget.imageDIR;
        super.initState();
      }
    
      //This is unnecessary
      @override
      void didUpdateWidget(UserCard oldWidget) {
        super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
        if(!vars.loadFromTabletStorage) {
          saveImage();
          img = NetworkImage(vars.globalURL + 'api/getUserAvatar/' + id.toString());
        }
        /*else {
          Future<FileImage> imageData = getLocalImage();
          img = imageData;//Image.file(File(imageData.toString()), width: vars.userPictureWidth, height: vars.userPictureHeigth);
        }*/
        print('CONNECTION STATUS ::: ' + (img == null).toString());
    
        //Example: '\nDAVID R.\n'
        String formattedNameSurname = '\n' +
            this.name.toUpperCase() +
            ' ' +
            this.surname.toString().substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
            '.\n';
    
        double imageWidth = (this.imageDIR.contains('WorkerSmall.png'))
            ? vars.userDefaultWorkerPictureWidth
            : vars.userPictureWidth;
    
        return Expanded(
          child: Container(
            color: vars.defaultBackgroundColor,
            width: vars.userContainerWidth,
            height: vars.userContainerHeigth,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Material(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 246, 246, 246),
                  child: InkWell(
                    
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: imageWidth + 3,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.grey, //Color(0xFFFDCF09),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: imageWidth,
                        backgroundImage: img,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  formattedNameSurname,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  title.toUpperCase() /*+'\n\n\n'*/,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 14.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }

      Future<Uint8List> _readLocallyImageFile() async {
        // Retrieve "External Storage Directory" for Android and "NSApplicationSupportDirectory" for iOS
        Directory directory = Platform.isAndroid
            ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
            : await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    
        print('>>>>>>>>>>>> ' + directory.path);
        // Create a new file. You can create any kind of file like txt, doc , json etc.
        File file =
        await File('${directory.path}/' + (id-1).toString() + '.png').create();
    
        // Read the file content
        Uint8List fileContent = await file.readAsBytes();
        print("AVATAR FILE CONTENTS:\n$fileContent\n========================================");
        return fileContent;
      }
    
      Future<FileImage> getLocalImage() async{
        Directory directory = Platform.isAndroid
            ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
            : await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    
        File file =
        await File("${directory.path}/" + id.toString() + '.png').create();
        return FileImage(file);
      }
    
      Future<void> saveImage() async {
        // Retrieve "External Storage Directory" for Android and "NSApplicationSupportDirectory" for iOS
        Directory directory = Platform.isAndroid
            ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
            : await getApplicationSupportDirectory();
    
        var response =
            await http.get(vars.globalURL + 'api/getUserAvatar/' + id.toString());
        print(response.toString());
        File file =
            await File("${directory.path}/" + id.toString() + '.png').create();
        file.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the CachedNetworkImage for that.

The pacakge : [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I used exactly the same example and now I am able to cache avatars and thumbnails when I am online only once and I can display them even when I am offline.